# DB server TLS configuration. Failures TNS-00542: SSL Handshake failed

Tags: oracle, ssl, oracle11g, tls1.2

I am trying to configure my db server to work with TLS.
Created server wallet with server certificate, defined listener with tcps protocol, now I am trying to restart the listener.

I have not configured client that located on the same machine. I want my application act as a client and this client will be configured later.

Performing `lsnrctl stop` I receive an exception like

```
Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCPS)(HOST=myhost.com)(PORT=1521)))
ORA-28759: failure to open file
 TNS-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error
  TNS-00540: SSL protocol adapter failure

ORA-28864: SSL connection closed gracefully
 TNS-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error
  TNS-00542: SSL Handshake failed
```

Usually this exception happens when server certificate is not located on trust store, or handshake failed. Could you please advise me:

1. Maybe I am missing something, any direction?
2. Maybe I need configure also client side?
3. Ho to turn on and find logs?

Comment: Please refer this : 
 https://support.oracle.com/knowledge/Oracle%20Database%20Products/467142_1.html#REF . You would need an Oracle Support Account it seems and login into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I configured oracle with MUTUAL authentication, however on client side haven't put the keystore, that is why received handshake exception.

Need to add some parameters for java on client side (application)

```
export JAVA_OPTS ="$JAVA_OPTS -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=path/truststore.jks"
export JAVA_OPTS ="$JAVA_OPTS -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=changeIT"
export JAVA_OPTS ="$JAVA_OPTS -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=path/keystore.jks"
export JAVA_OPTS ="$JAVA_OPTS -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=changeIT"
```

Now problem was solved.